# Transfer or backup data before/after user deletion

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, office365-restapi, azure-ad-graph-api

We've been experimenting Office 365 REST APIs and wondering if we can transfer a to-be-deleted or deleted user's data (like documents, sheets) to another active user of the organization or the Admin.

The O365 Admin console doesn't seem to be offering any UI to achieve this nor do I find any REST APIs exposed via AAD Graph or MS Graph.

Please let know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We've been experimenting Office 365 REST APIs and wondering if we can transfer a to-be-deleted or deleted user's data (like documents, sheets) to another active user of the organization or the Admin.

The [Office 365 REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog) doesn't provide this kind of API to transfer the data from one tenant to another for the deleted user's data.

However if you want to transfer the data( it dendends on how you defing your data), you may consider using the Microsoft Graph API. For example, we can use Microsoft Graph API to download/upload the data from OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, and SharePoint document libraries.

More detail about the Microsoft Graph API, you can refer [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview).

Comment: Thanks Fei! It's not about transferring data from one tenant to another. it's about transferring data between users belonging to the same organization, when one of them has to be terminated or deleted for some reason. Also, is it possible to directly transfer (or migrate) the files in OneDrive? Downloading and uploading files seem to be cumbersome.

Comment: @asgs The OneDrive doesn't provide the feature for transfer the files between account.  To achieve the goal, there are also the third-party tools which can do this job. You can research this topic from internet.